# Trouble linking sfml files using g++

Tags: sfml, linker-errors

I downloaded the sfml GCC - 32-bit version for linux; though my operating system is ubuntu.  I am able to compile a test program, but when I try to link the libraries I get an error:

```
dylan@Aspire-one:~/Documents/SFML-2.3.1/projects$ g++ test.o -o sfml-app -L/home/dylan/Documents/SFML-2.3.1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
/home/dylan/Documents/SFML-2.3.1/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If you have any clues please comment below, but I would appreciate a full answer.

Comment: It looks like you have SFML binaries that are linked to a version of glibc that isn't on your system.  You need to either install that version of glibc (3.4.20, 32 bit) or get/build SFML binaries that link to a version of glibc that you do have.

Comment: I am not currently able to install anything because I do not have root privileges.  How would I go about the second suggestion?

Comment: Apparently the download does not come with the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my earlier comment:  It looks like you have SFML binaries that are linked to a version of glibc that isn't on your system.  You need to either install that version of glibc (3.4.20, 32 bit) or get/build SFML binaries that link to a version of glibc that you do have.

The Linux world is different from the Windows and the Mac worlds.  And the right way to do things has changed over the years.  And my personal willingness to experiment has changed as well.

You generally want to get binaries from the distribution you use.  Ubuntu in your case, Fedora in mine.  This allows the package manager (e.g., yum or apt-get) to do its job:  determine if you have the needed prerequisites when installing new software, uninstall software as desired, install updates with minimal fuss, etc.  If you can't get the binaries you want, at least try to find a repository that you can tell your package manager to trust, so that you can get regular updates.

If you aren't able to find an acceptable package that way, your only option is to build from source.  Download the latest source code archive from http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php (get a release with a version number, instead of "whatever's currently in GitHub").  It looks like SFML currently uses CMake, so you'll want to follow the directions on http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/compile-with-cmake.php to build.

Personally, I wouldn't run the final `make install` step.  That will copy the binaries to `/usr/local` or some similar place, but won't notify your package manager about the change.  And there won't be a way to uninstall aside from manually deleting the files.  Instead, just add the folder you build in to your `PATH` (and the `include` folder to your `INCLUDE_PATH`).  You'll be able to develop your application with that setup, and nothing will prevent you from installing the package when somebody finally creates it for your distribution.